# How to add numbers from multiple files and write to another file using unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have five files as shown below, with the single line with comma separated value

File 1

```
abc,100
```

File 2

```
abc,200
```

File 3

```
abc,300
```

File 4

```
abc,700
```

File 5

```
abc,800
```

I need the output as by adding the numbers from all above files.
the output script should be in the single line code.

Output file

```
abc,2100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{code=$1; total += $2} END {printf("%s,%d\n", code, total)}' file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 > outputfile
```

Comment: Thanks, If second file has bbc,200 then i should get like abc_bbc,2100

Comment: That's a very different question. You shouldn't edit this question, you should post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk -F\, '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in a){print i","a[i]}}' file* > target
```

This will be usable for mutiple `key` input files.

For the *new* expected output:

```
awk -F\, '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in a){key=key"_"i;cont+=a[i]};sub(/^_/,"",key);print key","cont}' file*
```

**Results**

```
abc_bbc,2100
```

Comment: Thanks, If second file has bbc,200 then i should get like abc_bbc,2100

Comment: You should ask in another post , i updated my answer anyway